# make an object in xml that would have the width and height of half of the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

For the xml line:
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, is there a const value like fill_parent/2? I want my object to fill only half of the screen and not all of it.

Comment: may go with layout_weight property

Comment: <blink><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/list_fav"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView></blink>

Comment: when i try to paste it it comes with space instead of "enter"s... and I can't find the right format in the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "weight" of the linear layout for this purpose. e.g. if you want to divide available space between two control:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

for proportionate dimension use `Layout_weight` method for LinearLayout .
for your case

```
<Linearlayout weight_sum=2>
  <yourView layout_weight=1 />
</Linearlayout>
```

//sudo syntax

Comment: i don't use a layout, my code is for a list view, and I made it by the android.com tutorial that said to make an xml file with only a TextView

Comment: hmmmmmmm ........ seems you are using arrayAdapter instead of a custom adapter . no worries ,just pass R.layout.name and R.id.textviewid . for more help paste code snippate

Comment: Ok, so I switch the R.layout.name with the R.layout.TextViewID... then what?... and if I want to show you my code, how do I do that? I can't understand from the format help how to make a block to post a code